# How can I stop the Instagram from sending two post requests (or how could I filter repetitive posts)

Tags: instagram

I am not sure if it is because of my settings or my subscriptions or a flaw with the API, but every time the Instagram API sends me a POST (because I am subscribed to an update for a special hash tag), I actually receive two identical posts.  This is a little frustrating so I would like to stop it if I could.

If I can not stop it automatically, is there a way to filter out identical http requests? I download a file each time something I receive a notification and I would like to keep this process efficient.